# Distorted menu bar when zooming out the page

Tags: html, css

guys i need help on my menus. when i zoom out of page it gets distorted. heres my link. i tested this link on IE, it's just fine, but in chrome and firefox zooming the page would distort the menu and the contents below.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22813136/Finding%20Nemo%20Inc/FNemo_front.htm#

Comment: guys i have figured it out now. the problem was i set my width of the menus in the 

#menu ul li a{}, wherein i should have set the width  in the #menu ul li{} and use % instead of px. but thanks a lot Mr green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've placed each menu item in its own `ul` container like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

Try instead using one single ul with multiple lis as such

```
<ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

Then you'll need to do some css to get them to align vertically. It's a bit extra work, but it's the right way. Otherwise you'll be trying to fix the structure's appearance that is built to be broken in the first place. :)

Here's one way to do that: http://jamesowers.co.uk/css-tutorials/10/vertical-list-menu/

Comment: I'm looking at it now, and you still have each item in its own ul.

Comment: look at it again. and zoom out or in. it wont distort anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `div#text-contents` was inheriting the above div float property. to remove it you should Give `clear:both` to `div#text-contents` it will work fine. I suggest you to use percentages for widths instead of giving pixels. (not necessary)

Comment: no sir, it didnt solve the problem.. i also tried replacing the px with % for my widths, still the same.